# Manifold is $2$nd countable iff it has a countable atlas

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I am trying to prove that if a smooth manifold has a countable atlas than it has a countable basis.
If I have $(U_n, \varphi_n)$ a countable atlas, how can I find a basis of the topology? If I take the set obtained by $U_n$ and all possible finite intersections, it will be a basis but is not guaranteed it will be countable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints**

1. $U_n$ are open subsets of Euclidean spaces, what can you tell me about the basis for its induced topology?
2. A set $S$ can be written as $\cup_{n} (U_n\cap S)$. What does this tell you about the relationship between the base of the topology of the manifold, and the bases of the topologies of the charts?
3. You may need to use the statement "A countable union of countable sets is countable." This statement is not provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone, but is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice. When studying topology this statement can be safely assumed to be true.

Comment: 1. Through $\varphi_n$, $U_n$ has a countable basis $(B_n^m)_{m \in \mathbb N} .\\$ 2. $$ \left\lbrace \bigcup_{n \in C, m \in D} B_n^m : C, D \subset \mathbb N \right\rbrace $$ is a basis of $M$ and by 3. it is countable.

Comment: Yep. That looks okay.